# Resolved [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction]

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend

I have been trying to make a post to my rest API but i don't know why i get the error:
`WARN 604 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction].`

I have tried to do the connection to the API with a DTO, with a String, but nothing, I'm not so experienced so i don't know how to solve it.

I tried to do it with the body as just the message, then a DTO with the property message only, then the type Chat, but noting

The service part:

```
@Transactional()
    public Chat saveChat(String message){
        Chat newChat = new Chat();
        Game recentGame = gameService.findRecentGameByPlayerId();
        Player currentPlayer = playerService.findPlayerByUser(userService.findCurrentUser().getId()).orElse(null);

        if (recentGame.getStartedAt() != null && currentPlayer != null) {
            newChat.setGame(recentGame);
            newChat.setPlayer(currentPlayer);
            newChat.setMessage(message);
            return chatRepository.save(newChat);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No se pudo encontrar el juego o el jugador.");
        }
    }
```

The controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/{gameId}/chat")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Chat> createChat(@RequestBody MessageDTO message) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(chatService.saveChat(message.getMessage()), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

The frontend:

```
    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const message = {
            id:"",
            game: game.id,
            player: user.id,
            message: chatMessage
        };
        
        fetch(`/api/v1/games/${id}/chat`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(message),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.message) {
                    setMessage(data.message);
                    setVisible(true);
                } else {
                }
            })
            .catch((message) => alert(message));
    }
```

The type Chat

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat")
@Setter
@Getter
public class Chat extends BaseEntity{

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 0, max = 100)
    String message;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Game game;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Player player;
}
```

Comment: Also another error is that the message is always null